# Change Apache Drill parquet fragments size on S3

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-drill

I'm working with apache-drill-1.17.0 (./bin/drill-embedded) and storing my data on S3.
I've run the following commands:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET `store.parquet.block-size` = 1073741824;
```

and added to core-site.xml:

```
</property>
    <property>
    <name>fs.s3a.block.size</name>
    <value>256M</value>
</property>
```

But each time I run a command like:

```
CREATE TABLE entities (a, b, c,...) AS SELECT a, b, c,... FROM entities_view
```

I get few fragments, 32M each.
How can I control their size?